# How to edit data on client side, without querying a database twice

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, client

I have an MVC application that displaying ads. Here is the view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarbonSmartsolution.Models.Ad>


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="border-bottom-0  bg-transparent">
            <td class="border-bottom-0">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.desciption)
                </td>                              
        </tr>
    }
```

When all ads are displayed. A user can click on specific ad to display details information. How can I do that without querying the DB since all the information is already passed in the Model?

Comment: Hidden fields with your data

Comment: `Html.HiddenFor` springs to mind